# How to configure firebase hosting for angular i18n PWAs?

Tags: angular, firebase, internationalization, firebase-hosting

Firebase Hosting has a very nice internationalization feature [Firebase i18n rewrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/i18n-rewrites)

It lets you deploy your angular i18n app, each language is located in its own sub folder. eg:
/en
/de

When you open your myProject.com Domain, firebase switches, based on your location, language preferences etc to the right language subfolder. This works very good. EG:
myProject.com -> myProject.com/en

My question is:

How do i have to configure firebase.json, to also do this, if the user opens a url with a path.
EG:
if the user opens
myproject.com/foo/bar -> it should redirect to myProject.com/de/foo/bar
which it does not.

Here is the part of the firebase.json that i am using:

```
"hosting": {
"public": "www",
"ignore": [
  "firebase.json",
  "**/.*",
  "**/node_modules/**"
],
"i18n": {
  "root": "/"
},
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/en/index.html"
  }
]
```

Under Rewrites i have one rule configured to just switch to the /en version, but i would love to use the same "magic" that firebase provides for the Domain without path. Is there a way without a cloud function?

**UPDATE:**
As requested in the comments, the file structure is

```
www
/de
/en
```

There are no files directly in www, just the 2 sub folders for each language.
Inside each language folder, there are the typical pwa angular files like index.html, and a bunch of js files.

Comment: Can you show your file structure under the `www` directory?

Comment: Yes. I have updated the post aboce with the file structure

Comment: have you found an answer?